# SwiftUI List rows not adhering to clipped frame height despite setting .defaultMinListRowHeight to 0

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to create a SwiftUI `List` with varying row heights defined by clipped `VStack`s. However, I'm finding that the rows don't match the clipped frame height of the VStacks, even though I've set the .defaultMinListRowHeight to 0.

Here's a code to reproduce the issue:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
                VStack{
                    Text("TEST")
                    Text("TEST")
                    Text("TEST")
                    Text("TEST")
                    Text("TEST")
                }
                .background(.gray)
                .frame(height: 5)
                .clipped()
                .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                VStack{
                    Text("TEST")
                    Text("TEST")
                    Text("TEST")
                    Text("TEST")
                }
                .background(.purple)
                .frame(height: 10)
                .clipped()
                .listRowBackground(Color.red)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                VStack{
                    Text("TEST")
                    Text("TEST")
                    Text("TEST")
                }
                .background(.green)
                .frame(height: 15)
                .clipped()
                .listRowBackground(Color.blue)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}
```

Which results in the following:

[image: Code result]

The expected result is that each row will follow the frame height of the contained VStack, but it's not happening.

Can anyone explain why this is not working as expected, and how I can achieve the desired effect? Any insights or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to simply add a `GeometryReader`:

```
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack{
                Text("TEST")
                Text("TEST")
                Text("TEST")
                Text("TEST")
            }
        }
            .background(.purple)
            .frame(height: 20)
            .clipped()
            .listRowBackground(Color.red)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
```